# Javascript event not working

Tags: javascript, php

I have this php code below

```
<?php foreach($items in $item) : ?>
<a class="btn">$item</a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

and this javascript below

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    console.log('hello');
});
```

it should work when I click the `<a>` tag but it's not working.
So, help me please. (Sorry for bad English)

Comment: any error in console??

Comment: What do you expect? What do you get?

Comment: are you sure yuor php foreach loop is not throwing error ? http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Also you need to bind click events after the dom is ready. https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Since you question is about problem in JavaScript please provide HTML + JavaScript sample. As pointed out in comment/answer your PHP code is wrong altogether - so it is hard to say if error is caused by something in your HTML/script  or not related to JavaScript at all.

Comment: @Phil_1984_ link to good explanation of why you believe "need to bind click events after the dom is ready" would be much more useful than link to `ready`. (Since statement by itself is false).

Comment: You certainly don't "need" to use ready. My appologies. But the DOM elements need to exist first before you can bind events on them. Using ready can fix bugs where the DOM needs to be ready but isn't.

Answer (score 5):

`foreach($items in $item)` this is wrong. php `foreach` uses `as` not `in`

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 0):

Use either

```
<?php foreach($items as $item) : 
    echo "<a class='btn'>".$item."</a>"
endforeach; ?>
```

or

```
<?php foreach($items as $item):?>
<a class='btn'><?php echo $item>?></a>"
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

$item must be within `<?php ... ?>` or it's meaningless to php

Answer (score 0):

Did you add jQuery library link into it? because you used "$".

Just declare jquery library before your script. It should works

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js

p/s: also fix php syntax as Ramanlfc mentioned above